# $10 \times 10$ board travel

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

You are given a $10 \times 10$ board and a figure that can move $3$ fields up, down, left or right, or $2$ fields diagonally in each direction. Is there any possible way of visiting **every** field of the board, so that you never visit the same field twice, and, if there is, which is it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly possible. One example:

[image]

Basically, you can keep moving vertically & horizontally until you run out of fields, and then do a single diagonal movement, and again and again.